# Connect to SharePoint app/addin from third party web application/server

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

[image]

I need to get files that are in a SharePoint site to a third party server. In the request by custom server, all file paths given. I need to set up an endpoint to get that request and send requested files to server.

I'm not allowed to use SharePoint REST API.

I need to get this done through an addin/app. Is this kind of approach possible with an addin/app? if yes then how?

Comment: Regarding "I'm not allowed to use SharePoint REST API". For what reason are you not allowed to use the SharePoint REST API? Does this same restriction apply to APIs like the SharePoint Client Object Model (CSOM) or Microsoft Graph?

Comment: @rob-windsor This is a restriction made by customer that I'm working with. It meant that I can't directly make a request to SharePoint REST API from my custom server. I'm pretty much new to this context. I think customer made that for a security reason. I need to develop an app to add in to specific SharePoint site in customer SharePoint installation. Customer expecting an app that can be added to SP site like this approach. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-app-to-a-site-ef9c0dbd-7fe1-4715-a1b0-fe3bc81317cb

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a general guide to get you started.

Use CSOM or PNP core on your desired language (Powershell, C#) for example.

- https://pnp.github.io/powershell/
- https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/

Register your Addin/app either through addin invitation or azure permissions:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/register-sharepoint-add-ins

Use authentication through your app in the desired library and do whatever you need!